# Why do not the parameter values ​change using the trainAuto () function of the SVM class of OpenCV 3.4?

Tags: java, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

OpenCV says that trainAuto() function trains an SVM with optimal parameters.
Every time I train with trainAuto(), the parameters that are obtained are the same. According to this, the values ​​of the parameters should change if, for example, I change the value of kFold.

I tried to change the values ​​of kFold but I still get the same values ​​in the parameters.

The code I am using is the following:

```
SVM svm = SVM.create();
svm.setType(SVM.C_SVC);
svm.setKernel(SVM.SIGMOID);


ParamGrid cgrid = ParamGrid.create();
ParamGrid gammaGrid = ParamGrid.create();
ParamGrid pGrid = ParamGrid.create();
ParamGrid nuGrid = ParamGrid.create();
ParamGrid coeffGrid = ParamGrid.create();
ParamGrid degreeGrid = ParamGrid.create();         

int kFold = 10;     
svm.trainAuto(train, Ml.ROW_SAMPLE, labels, kFold, cgrid, gammaGrid, 
pGrid, nuGrid, coeffGrid, degreeGrid, false);

double C = svm.getC();
double gamma = svm.getGamma();
double P = svm.getP();
double Nu = svm.getNu();
double Coef0 = svm.getCoef0();
double Degree = svm.getDegree();

System.out.println("C: " +C);
System.out.println("Gamma: " +gamma); 
System.out.println("P: " +P);
System.out.println("Nu: " +Nu);
System.out.println("Coeff: " +Coef0);
System.out.println("Degree: " +Degree);
```

The results that I always get are the following:

`C: 1.0
Gamma: 1.0
P: 0.0
Nu: 0.0
Coeff: 0.0
Degree: 0.0`

What am I doing wrong?